# Why are input and output generally "write once" or "immutable" files? Also what is the structure of a MapReduce program?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have an exam this week and I am working through the study guide. I am struggling with the answer to these two questions. I've emailed my Professor, but he's yet to get back to me so I thought I'd try here. Anyone know the answer to these two questions?

- Why are input and output generally "write once" or "immutable" files?
- What is the structure of a MapReduce program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html

Instead, all data elements in MapReduce are immutable, meaning that they cannot be updated. If in a mapping task you change an input (key, value) pair, it does not get reflected back in the input files; communication occurs only by generating new output (key, value) pairs which are then forwarded by the Hadoop system into the next phase of execution.

this paragraph from the link above may help

Answer (score -1):

You cannot change that you sent or received a value, nor change the value.

A *map* operation returns a new object related to a single input object.

A *reduce* operation aggregates a single value from its inputs.

A map-reduce program would do both.